# Strange behaviour of the dock after opening a maximized window

Tags: elementary-os, pantheon

I have tried Elementary OS through a DVD and when I had a window (not maximized) after I maximized it and closed it then when I re-opened it there was a weird jumpy behaviour in the dock. The window was like colliding for a moment with the dock and then the dock disappeared (as it should). That is not happening if you maximize the window but only if you re-open it after closing it (after having it maximized). In the first case there is a smooth "transition" and in the second it is pretty weird. Is that a bug? As I have tried it only through a DVD is that happening if you have it installed?

Comment: If you don't want to make local installation yet, I'd suggest you to install to an external flash drive instead i.e. create a Live USB. It is much faster than a Live CD/DVD. Running from a CD/DVD would always dependent on the reading mechanism of an optical drive.